# Laravel Eloquent find returning null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve a record from my database using Eloquents find method, however, it's unexpectedly returning null. If I run the query manually on the database then it returns the expected record.

I'm using the following in Laravel:

```
$support = Support::find(02155);
```

And the following directly on the database:

```
SELECT * FROM support WHERE id = 02155;
```

The primary key column is named 'id' with type smallint(5), unsigned and zerofill along with auto increment set. I based the above 'manual' query on the Laravel documentation according to what Laravel should be executing.

There aren't any errors reported (that I can see) and if I alter Eloquent method to 'all' then all of the records are correctly returned.

Comment: Since the column is int the real value of id is 2155 not 02155. It shouldn't really be a problem but maybe you should try it without that zero?

Comment: You were right! That never occurred to me. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it :).

Comment: You could provide an answer to your question and accept it to help others that come across it and help us know which questions about laravel weren't solved yet :). It will also count to your SO reputation and badges.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is caused because numbers starting with 0 are considered an octal by PHP, as per: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

It seems that PHP converts the number to a decimal before executing the MySQL query which means the query is formed with an incorrect number.

For example:

```
Support::find(02155);
```

Becomes:

```
'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 1133'
```

### The Solution

I resolved this by typecasting the number to an integer using (int) before I used it with Eloquents find method. It will also work if you pass the number as a string (i.e. in quotes), like so:

```
Support::find('02155');
```

Comment: Loved to you see you followed my suggestion. Got upvoted for that and the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There could be another problem.

If you used soft delete in your model and find the record from the database with find, null may be returned.
To solve this problem, you can remove the soft delete from your model.