# Laravel Eloquent::Find() returning NULL with an existing ID

Tags: php, laravel, orm, find, eloquent

It's pretty straightforward as it's the most basic thing but I don't know what I'm missing:

Having a model called `Site`

I'm using Eloquent ORM, so when I call (in a controller)

```
$oSite = Site::find(1)
```

and then

```
var_dump($oSite);
```

It returns a value of `NULL`.

But when I check the database, the table 'sites' actually contains the following item:

```
id: 1
user_id: 1
name: test
```

In my `Site` **model** I have the following code:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

 Class Site extends Eloquent {

        protected $table = 'sites';

        protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'name'];
 }
```

Instead, if I gather the item with the following:

```
$oSite = DB::table('sites')
                ->where('id', 1)
                ->first();
```

It works and I get the correct register.

What I'm doing wrong? Which part of the documentation I didn't get?

**EDIT:**

Model code can be checked above.

**Controller**:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
class SiteManagementController extends BaseController {

...

    public function deleteSite()
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            $iSiteToDelete = Input::get('siteId');

            $oSite = Site::find($iSiteToDelete);

            return var_dump($oSite);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2: (SOLVED)**

**Real reason why wasn't working:**

I had **originally** in my model code the following:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

Class Site extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'sites';

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'name'];
}
```

Problem was I added a '`deleted_at`' column after I started the project and when I applied migrations, I didn't have softdeleting enabled.
Obviously, I did a second error, forgetting to enable '`deleted_at`' to be nullable, hence all inserts went had a wrong timestamp (0000-00-00 ...).

Fix:

1. Made nullable '`deleted_at`' column.
2. Set all wrong '`deleted_at`' timestamps to `NULL`.

Comment: Show the model and controller method instead.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk edited post and added Contoller method. Model 'Site' is above.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk solved by self. Problem source was DB related.

Answer (score 1):

Check you are getting `Input::get('siteId')` correctly. if you are getting it then try to convert it into integer i.e

```
$iSiteToDelete = intval(Input::get('siteId'));
```

Comment: Yes, after var_dumping Input::get('siteId') I got the correct value.

Comment: are you getting integer value in var_dump?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326140/laravel-eloquent-find-returning-null) please check this link

Comment: Checked the link. And no, Input::get('siteId') returned a string, instead of intval

Comment: yes, it is working now, but not because of the typechange. Now Site::find($iSiteToDelete) is working even being $iSiteToDelete is actually a string.
What did happen? I really have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning your model.

`var_dump` prints output and returns nothing.

do this instead:

```
dd($oSite); // stands for var_dump and die - a helper method
```

and even better, simply return the model:

```
return $oSite; // will be cast to JSON string
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a custom query with the `DB` facade. I neglected to skip records that have a `deleted_at` in my DB query. When showing all the records, it worked with IDs that had already been deleted, so methods like find that if they were considering the `deleted_at`, did not find the record.

Layer eight.

Answer (score 0):

For the future if you encounter a similar problem you can check what SQL queries laravel is sending to the database.

Todo so just enable query logging by using `DB` facade:

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();
```

Before sending request to database.
Then after using `find()` or `get()` you can get all requests by:

```
\DB::getQueryLog();
```

You can `getQueryLog` into `dd()` function and see what database queries were made.