# Eloquent has() in Many-To-Many

Tags: php, eloquent, relationships

I'm having a simple blog system, with a `posts`, `tags` and `posts_tags` table. The `posts` and `tags` table both have an `id` and a `content` field, whereas the `posts_tags` table has the fields `post_id` and `tag_id`. My eloquent models are:

```
class Post extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'posts_tags', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Tag extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Post', 'posts_tags', 'tag_id', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

Now, as far as I understood, if I call `Post::has('tags')->get()` I should get the posts which have at least one tag (which all do). But all I get is an empty array (which I get when calling `Tag::has('posts')->get()`, too). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem in this question: [Laravel Eloquent::Find() returning NULL with an existing ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139886/laravel-eloquentfind-returning-null-with-an-existing-id)

Problem was, I was using soft deletes

```
class Post extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'posts_tags', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
    }
}
```

But my `deleted_at` column wasn't nullable.