# Laravel 5.1 find eloquent returns null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I've this model Customer :

```
<?php
 namespace App\Models;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\softDeletes;

   class Customer extends Model
   {
        use SoftDeletes;
        protected $table = 'customers';
        public $timestamps = true;
        protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
        protected $fillable = ['name', ...
        ...
```

What I can't understand is :
When I try this :

```
$customer = Customer::all();                
dd($customer);
```

I get results

and when trying this :

```
$customer = Customer::find(1);                
dd($customer);
```

I get `null`.

Comment: How is the schema of your Customer table?

Comment: If you are using softDelete Added `deleted_at` column to customers table ?

Comment: Schema::create('customers', function(Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('name', 150);
   $table->string('address', 255);
   $table->string('tel', 30);   
   $table->string('fax', 30);
   $table->softDeletes();
   $table->timestamps();   
  });

Comment: what do you get from `Customer::all()` because that will **always** return a collection.

Comment: Are you 100% sure there's a `Customer` with an `id` of 1? The `find()` function will only return something if the id is found in the customers table. Maybe try `first()` instead and see what that returns... `Customer::first()`

Comment: In Customer table, records are available for id = 1 ?

Comment: Yes I'm 200% sure that there's a customer with ID 1,
I said if I try Customer::all() I get results without any problem !!!!

Comment: Can you please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139886/laravel-eloquentfind-returning-null-with-an-existing-id

Comment: Thanks @PrashantGPatil 
seeing your link, it works fine if I set :
$customer = DB::table('customers')
                ->where('id', 1)
                ->first();                
        dd($customer);
but why the first code doesn't work ????

Comment: Refer model file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139886/laravel-eloquentfind-returning-null-with-an-existing-id.

Comment: are you using mysql?

Comment: Yes I'm using  MySQL

Comment: Ok thanks all for your assistance
I solved my issue by following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139886/laravel-eloquentfind-returning-null-with-an-existing-id
and I drop the table and recreate it, and all is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

With that `$customer = Customer::find(1);` you're just trying to get the customer that have primary key "1".

With `Customer::all();` you get all of your customer.

The reason you got null is because you haven't any customer with id 1 in your database (maybe has been deleted).