# TCPDF get value from database

Tags: php, laravel, tcpdf

I'm trying to get a value from the database. I want to get the name of id '17'.
I'm using **Laravel 5.4 and Tcpdf**

This is my controller code:

```
public function createpdf($id) {

    $scan = Scan::find($id);    
    $pdf = new \TCPDF();

    $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->Text(90, 140, 'Test');

    $filename = storage_path() . $scan->name . '.pdf';



    $pdf->output($filename, 'F');

    return \Response::download($filename);

}
```

The error i get: `Trying to get property of non-object`

How do i fix this? A foreach doesn't do the trick..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if `$scan` is even valid and what does your `find` function return.

It is possible, that there is no DB record for specific ID. From your error, it is clearly, that result was not object (is it array?).

Use `var_dump($scan);` to inspect result of find.

Maybe like this?

```
public function createpdf($id) {
    $scan = Scan::find($id);
    var_dump($scan);
    if (!$scan) {
        return; //or something
    }
```

Possible solution with model structure problem:

[Laravel Eloquent::Find() returning NULL with an existing ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139886/laravel-eloquentfind-returning-null-with-an-existing-id)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. The var dump gives me null. Does this mean it can't find my id?

Comment: I've updated my answer with link to possible solution you should verify.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've found the 'problem': Laravel likes to log you out if you're online for a long time. I was refreshing the not working page over and over again. I've decided to login again and it works... Thanks for the help tho! :)