# laravel find returning null when trying to do an update

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do an update with my data but when I try to pass $object to another view it is returning me null value. I did a dd($id) and it return me the id that I wanted but if I do a dd($object) return me null. I have check similar question to this such as [Laravel Eloquent::Find() returning NULL with an existing ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139886/laravel-eloquentfind-returning-null-with-an-existing-id) but still doesn't work. Everyone say that the problem comes from the database, but I don't understand which part. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot

VerificationController:

```
 public function editVerify($id){
    $object = Verification::find($id);
    dd($object);
    return view('editVerify', compact('object'));
}
```

Verification Model:

```
     public function personal_infos() {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\PersonalInfo", "id", 'user_id');
}
```

PersonalInfo model:

```
                public function verifications() {
return $this->hasOne('App\Verification','user_id');
```

}

This is what it look like in the database(some value are NULL while some contain data)
[image]
[image]
Verification table:

```
  Schema::create('verifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
              $table->string('Nationality');
            $table->string('identity_type');
            $table->string('residential_status');
            $table->string('NRIC_check');
            $table->string('nric_number1');
            $table->string('blacklist');
            $table->string('whiteCard');
            $table->string('educational_cert');
            $table->string('WSQ_cert');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned(); 
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('personal_infos');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Provide Verification model details and dd($id) , dd($object). Is your model to db table connection working??

Comment: Verification model is already in the question... dd($id) return me the id of the user while dd($object) return me null @Sohel0415

Comment: What does the Verification table structure look like?

Comment: Can you share the database table contents; especially the part where the record in question is present?

Comment: Inside Verification table, it contain name, certificate, nric and some other things but are NULL value

Comment: I have updated my questions @linuxartisan

Comment: I can't see an `id` column

Comment: Updated the question with the id @linuxartisan

Comment: Why can't I see `id` column in the migration code? Please provide that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159867/discussion-between-linuxartisan-and-dkna).

Comment: Added in, the id is always fixed in the migration so I thought there is no need for it in the question @linuxartisan

Comment: Is your create operation works??

Comment: It successfully migrated so ya @Sohel0415

Comment: not migration, when you make a update or create operation, is it work??

Comment: Yes it work @sohel0415

Comment: try this query exactly $v = Verification::where('id','=',$id)->first(); and dd($v)

Comment: It return me null

Comment: it seems you don't have a matching record for that id

Comment: But if I use this it shows the data, $v = Verification::where('user_id','=',$id)->first();
    dd($v);

Comment: @Dkna Because record is not match regarding `$id`, but it gives you result when `$id` is compared to `user_id`. So, if `$id=1`, in `Verification` table record not exist, but if you find record with `user_id`, it gives u result. So the problem is in your DB, not in your code!

Comment: Ohh I see, thank you for your explanation, in the past I was just updating normal records but this is a little different so I guess the method of updating it is also different, thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we use Eloquent `find()`, find method works with `primary key`. As you are using `find()` method to fetch data, it expects `id` as its parameter but you are looking to fetch records with `user_id`. So here is my solution-

```
$v=Verification::where('user_id','=',$id)->first();
```

or  make `user_id` column your `primary key`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and help @Sohel0415

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are working with `find()` of **Eloquent**, and it find record regarding to `'id'`, in your DB it not exists and it exists in your `user_id`  column!

So, change query to

```
$v=Verification::where('user_id','=',$id)->first();
```

And this gives you result OR change primary key to `user_id`

Hope this helps you!